# using dispatch on react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, dispatch

I am new to react and I'm trying to create a register and login page with react-redux and dispatch using the mern stack.

When I am calling the method the function did not run.

I have a file for the login page:

```
    import React from "react";
    import {login} from '../../actions/authActions';
    
    
    export class Login extends React.Component {
        
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        
        checkIfElementIsEmpty = (element) => {
            if (!element) {
                return false
            }
            if (element.value.length === 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        handleOnClickLogin = () =>
        {
            let usernameElement = document.getElementsByName("loginUsername")[0];
            let passwordElement = document.getElementsByName("loginPassword")[0];
    
            if (!this.checkIfElementIsEmpty(usernameElement))
            {
                usernameElement.style.backgroundColor = "#ff000042";
                return;
            }
            if (!this.checkIfElementIsEmpty(passwordElement))
            {
                passwordElement.style.backgroundColor = "#ff000042";
                return;
            }
            console.log("asd");
            login(usernameElement.value, passwordElement.value);
        }
    
        setColorToDefault = (e) =>{
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
        }
    
        render() {
            return <div className="base-container" ref={this.props.containerRef}>
                    <div className="header">Login</div>
                    <div className="content">
                        <div className="image">
                            {/* <img src={loginImg}/> */}
                        </div>
                        <div className="form">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="loginUsername" placeholder="username" onFocus={this.setColorToDefault}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" name="loginPassword" placeholder="password" onFocus={this.setColorToDefault}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="footer">
                        <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.handleOnClickLogin}>
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        }
    }
```

and a file called "authActions.js" with the function "login" that should send the request to the server and validate the login.

```
    export const login = (email, password) => (dispatch: Function) => {
        console.log("bbb");
        // Headers
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
            }
        }
    
      // Request body
      const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    
      axios
        .post('http://${HOST}:${PORT}/api/auth/login', body, config)
        .then(res =>
          dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
          })
        )
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch(
            returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'LOGIN_FAIL')
          );
          dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL
          });
        });
    }
```

When handleOnClickLogin is called, I only see the 'aaa' on the console. The 'bbb' is never being printed.
Why this is happening and how I need to use dispatch and react-redux correctly?

Comment: I feel you've seen the dispatch somewhere else. That's probably related to redux, you wouldn't use login function directly, but you need to bind it to redux with something like `import { connect } from 'react-redux';` But you'd need to specify your stack

Comment: Agreed, looks like you want `login` to be an asynchronous action. You would start by initially dispatching the `login` action, i.e. `dispatch(login(usernameElement.value, passwordElement.value));`, and the asynchronous redux middleware would handle processing your `login` action and pass `dispatch` to the curried function to be used later to dispatch further actions. You question needs ***a lot*** more context, it's not clear what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for your answer, I added more context to my question.

Comment: @aacotroneo Thanks! how should I use connect? I am using the mern stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs more detail, but I'll guess and give you an overview of what it should look like.

Redux has a `connect` method that basically will call a function you pass to it with a dispatch (and getState) parameter. So, given: `login = (email, password) => (dispatch: Function)`. You call `login(email, pass);` and it returns a function `(dispatch, [getState]) => xxx`. Redux will handle it by calling it with the store's dispatch.

For this to work, you'll also need to configure redux globally, a store, a provider, but I'm assuming your project already does that. Otherwise you'll need to go to the official docs which are really good https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/connect

However, if you're new to Redux and don't have all the `connect` set up, it'll be easier (and recommended way also) to use the Hooks API (It's also recommended in react to use Hooks rather than class components). https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#hooks

Back to your code, the important pieces you'll need:

```
import React from "react";
import { login } from '../../actions/authActions';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class MyLoginPage extends React.Component {

    handleOnClickLogin = () => {
     ...
     // calling the login bound by redux
     this.props.doLogin(usernameElement.value, passwordElement.value);
    } 

}

const LoginPageHOC = connect(null, {
  doLogin: login, // changing names for clarity (we could do login: login)
})(MyLoginPage);

export const LoginPage = LoginPageHOC; // use the HOC instead of the class
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try what you did and now I get "this.props.doLogin is not a function"

Comment: As I said, you need to configure everything else correctly. I explained what each part should do. In that case the connect will bind your login Action and pass it as a prop named doLogin. A mistake I made in my post is you don't need to export the LoginPage, but use the LoginPageHOC (editing)